# How to solve "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not ..."

Tags: swift

I'm working with swift 5 and I get the following error for the code below "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AdviceArticle'".

I saw a few similar issues dating back a few years but I cannot really translate the answers to my specific case.

```
static func loadAdviceArticle(articleID: String, completion: @escaping((AdviceArticle?) -> Void)) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("advice_articles").document(articleID).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        if let obj = try? snapshot?.data(as: AdviceArticle.self),
           let article = obj {
            completion(article)
        }
    }
}
```

Would you have a suggestion on how to fixe this code ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Move `let article = obj` *inside* the `{ }` -- it shouldn't be part of the `if` clause.

Comment: I added some broader context. Actually having the let article ... as part of the clause should be the logic. But the syntax seems to be wrong.

Comment: The answer is still the same. Your first `if let obj =` does an Optional binding. The second (`let article = objc`) is just a simple assignment -- not an optional binding. It should go *inside* the `{ }` as I said before. Or, ditch it completely and just have `completion(obj)` inside the `{ }`

Comment: @BenoitMorel Why do you think that should be the logic? `if let` clauses are only for optional values, so when you try to include a non-optional value (since `obj` was already unwrapped in the previous part of the clause) it correctly tells you that's wrong. Though I'm not sure why you're even reassigning the value in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery You were right, me arguing was due to a lack of knowledge. The solution provided worked perfectly well !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
guard let obj = try? snapshot?.data(as: AdviceArticle.self) else { return }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?